# Updating span is ok, updating input results in 'NaN'

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I'm converting prices using jquery and a php script that pulls in the latest exchange rate from Yahoo!

My update function is working on elements that I can update with .text() (eg span elements) but as soon as I try to set the .val() of my input element, it simple receives 'NaN' - even though I'm using the same value for both.

```
function frmtCurrency(ele,price) {
    // round the currency to the nearest .05
    price *= 2.0;
    price = price.toFixed(1) / 2.0;
    price = price.toFixed(2);

    //alert (parseInt(price)) here returns the amount, so it IS a number

    // check what type of element 'ele' is
    var element = (ele.get(0).tagName);

    if (element != 'INPUT') {
        ele.text(price+code); ALWAYS OK eg 10.55
    } else {
        ele.val(price); // ALWAYS NaN
    }
};
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't update an input field but I can update a span element

Comment: Suggest you do parseInt(price, 10); as the very first line of your function, before you attempt to do maths on it

Comment: I agree with Duncan. The price is probably a string (NaN) at some point. toFixed() may make it a string.. could just say `price = parseInt(price)` before setting the val.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: He's trying to use Floats, so he should use `parseFloat(price).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function frmtCurrency(ele,price) {
    // round the currency to the nearest .05
    price = parseFloat(price);
    if(isNaN(price)) { price = 0 }
    price *= 2.0;
    price = price.toFixed(1) / 2.0;
    price = price.toFixed(2);
    ele.val(price);
}

frmtCurrency($('input'), '');
```

Odds are you're passing a string or something wrong at some point in your software, giving you a NaN. Here you can see I pass a empty string and I add a handle to make it appear as a 0.00 when no real  number is given.

http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/DaHSA/1/

Comment: I was doing something royally stupid here that created the issue which I'm almost too embarrassed to confess... I was looking at the destination element and treating it accordingly, but not at the element that was providing the value in the first place. So I was relying on .text() to hand me the value, which of course worked for spans but not for input fields. Checking the input type and requesting the value accordingly made it all work. Thank you to everyone who suggested fixes for this, I promise not to be so stupid again :)

Comment: Heh, that stuff has happened to me before. Don't worry.